# Gradle ear build with dependencies from war file

Tags: java, gradle, war, ear

I am trying to build an **EAR** from a java multi project.
There are three different **WAR** projects and multiple **JAR** projects in this project. When I build the project all dependencies of **JAR** are imported into **ear-lib** and all dependencies of **WAR** projects are imported into their respective **WEB-INF/lib**. But all **WAR** projects uses many common **dependencies**. With this all of there dependencies the result **EAR** becomes very big in size(>100 mb). Is there any way to add all of the dependencies into one **EAR** file and none in the **WAR** files.

My **EAR build.gradle** looks like as below..

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'java'


configurations {
    earLib.extendsFrom runtime
    earLib.transitive = true
}

description = 'JavaEE6 Assembly'
dependencies {
  deploy project(path: ':WAR1', configuration: 'archives')
  deploy project(path: ':WAR2', configuration: 'archives')
  deploy project(path: ':WAR3', configuration: 'archives')

  earlib project(':CommonJAR1')
  earlib project(':CommonJAR2') 

  // Writing as below does not work in this case
  // earLib group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.1.1'
}

ear {
     archiveName='EARNAME.ear'
     libDirName 'lib'
     into("META-INF"){
        from("META-INF") 
     }

}
```

Following is one of the **WAR** file build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'


description = 'WAR2'
dependencies {
  compile project(':CommonJAR1')
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version:'1.9.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.2.3'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20090211'
    compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:'1.7.4'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.5'
    compile(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.15') {
exclude(module: 'mail')
exclude(module: 'jms')
exclude(module: 'jmxtools')
exclude(module: 'jmxri')
    }
    compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version:'1'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version:'1.2'
    runtime group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.1.1'
    runtime group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.7.5'
    runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.7.5'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version:'2.1'
}
```

I have tried any sources those I could find for doing the same, But none worked. Please suggest. The project is to be deployed on **WAS 8.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found this solution earlier, but was short on time so answering it now.

The **build.gradle** for **ear** should be as follows

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'java'


description = 'JavaEE6 Assembly'
dependencies {
  deploy project(path: ':WAR1', configuration: 'archives')
  deploy project(path: ':WAR2', configuration: 'archives')
  deploy project(path: ':WAR3', configuration: 'archives')

  earlib project(':CommonJAR')



}

def deployedModules = [ 'WAR1', 'WAR2', 'WAR3' ]

deployedModules.forEach {
    def projectPath = ":${it}"

    evaluationDependsOn(projectPath)

    findProject(projectPath).configurations.providedCompile.allDependencies.forEach {
        boolean isEarModule = it instanceof ProjectDependency &&
                (it as ProjectDependency).dependencyProject.name in deployedModules
        if (!isEarModule) {
            dependencies.add('earlib', it)
        }
    }
}

ear {
     archiveName='EARNAME.ear'
     libDirName 'lib'
     into("META-INF"){
        from("META-INF") 
     }
}
```

The **build.gradle** for the **war files** should be as follows

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'

description = 'WAR1'
dependencies {
  providedCompile project(':CommonJAR')
    providedCompile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version:'1.9.2'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-oxm', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version:'2.2.3'
    providedCompile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version:'20090211'
    providedCompile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE') {
exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
    }
    providedCompile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    providedCompile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version:'1.7.4'
    providedCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.5'
    compile(group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.15') {
exclude(module: 'jms')
exclude(module: 'jmxtools')
exclude(module: 'jmxri')
    }
    providedCompile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version:'1'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version:'1.2'
    providedCompile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version:'2.1.1'
    providedCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version:'4.0.5.RELEASE'
    providedCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'jcl-over-slf4j', version:'1.7.5'
    providedCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.7.5'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'jsp-api', version:'2.1'
    providedCompile group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis', version:'1.4'
}


war{
  manifest {
      attributes(
         "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
         "Class-Path": configurations.providedCompile.collect {" lib/" + it.getName() }.join(' ')
      )
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar so wanted to use some of whats going on here but I'm seeing a "Project with path ':CommonJAR' could not be found in project" error in the ear gradle file.  Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: CommanJar is the a jar module, if you have a jar module then add it.